# Handling multiple inputs with Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I have these two files that I want to get to work with Logstash and Elasticsearch.

File `1.txt`

```
chicago:green:big
california:orange:big
```

File `2.txt`

```
small:denver
medium:alaska
```

After reading these two files I want to get the following format with ElasticSearch: `size place`

I've been searching about how to configure Logstash in this particular way, but didn't find the way to do it properly.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/houses/%{filename}.txt"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        type => "%{filename}"
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "1.txt" {
        csv {
            separator => ":"
            columns => ["place", "color", "size"]
        }
    }
    if [type] == "2.txt" {
        csv {
            separator => ":"
            columns => ["size", "place"]
        }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Is this configuration file correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `1.txt` and `2.txt` are in `/houses/`, your `input->file->path` should probably be `/houses/*.txt`.

If I recall, the filename is in the `path` field, so your comparison would be:

```
if [path] == "1.txt" {
     ...
}
```

As an optimization, note that `path` can't be both "1.txt" and "2.txt", so you should be using if/else rather than if/if.

In your example, documents from 1.txt will have three fields, while those from 2.txt will have two.  If you're not interested in the `color` field, you can delete it with [mutate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-remove_field).